# Why am I getting a Call to a member function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a search function for my app. I keep getting the error:
"C:\wamp64\www\phonebook
Error
Call to a member function where() on array
http://localhost:8000/search"
My controller is:

```
enter code here
class SearchController extends Controller
{
public function index (Request $request) {
$user = Auth::user()->email;
$search = $request->search;

$mycon = DB::select('select * from phonebooks where user = :user', ['user' => $user])
->where('name', 'LIKE', '%:search%', ['search' => $search])
->orWhere('mobile', 'LIKE',  '%:search%', ['search' => $search])
->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%:search%', ['search' => $search])
->orWhere('other', 'LIKE', '%:search%', ['search' => $search])
->orWhere('notes', 'LIKE', '%:search%', ['search' => $search])
->get();

return view('index', compact('mycon'));
}
}
```